# CLI build with PrimeNG Components

Tags: angular, command-line-interface, angular-cli

Hi i love Angular CLI and get started in few seconds great job.
Well iam already using PrimeNG Angular 2 components and everthing works perfect now i want to use the build process of CLI.

So what i did i created a new project with CLI and using npm i installed the PrimeNG components. Now i am confused where should i have to enter the configuration settings for PrimeNG components.

Link of PrimeNG is http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/.

Comment: You need to use better English. Putting time and care into your post will encourage others to put care and time into their responses. This is your first post so I haven't voted it down straight away. However, spending time on writing coherent sentences is of particular importance when discussing programming, where statements are exact and precise in their meaning.

Comment: Take a look at the wiki for the CLI re: 3rd party libs... https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/3rd-party-libs if that doesn't guide you to a working solution, please expand your question with more details about your setup and what you've tried.

Comment: My main focus was to convey the problem, Which i did i guess. But i can understand what you meant to say.

Comment: Thank you Brocco i have done it Is there any docs are there which helps how to add CSS. Thanks –

Comment: See https://yakovfain.com/2016/10/28/adding-primeng-ui-components-to-angular-cli-project/ or http://blogs.bytecode.com.au/glen/2016/10/27/primeng-with-angular-cli.html for tutorials on CLI with PrimeNG

Comment: I've been looking for the same documentation, and wow Alexander McFarlane!  Why don't you offer a solution on top your rude comment. Maybe English isn't he's native language and it isn't better English, it's proper English!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a test project that work with angular cli with primeng.

[Angular2 Cli with PrimeNG](https://github.com/ishara/angular-cli-primeng)

Answer (score 0):

You should write your definitions to angular-cli.json when you use a component you should add that component to the app.module.ts imports part.
And for other css and js file you can use a configuration like this.

```
 "styles": [
    "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
    "../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css",
    "assets/layout/css/layout.css",
    "../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
    "../node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.css",
    "../node_modules/quill/dist/quill.snow.css",
    "../node_modules/nanoscroller/bin/css/nanoscroller.css",
    "../node_modules/animate.css/animate.css",
    "styles.css"
  ],
  "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
    "../node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js",
    "../node_modules/moment/moment.js",
    "../node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.js",
    "../node_modules/quill/dist/quill.js",
    "../node_modules/nanoscroller/bin/javascripts/jquery.nanoscroller.js"
  ]
```

Inside of your angular-cli.json file.